# Check whether an option exists inside a SelectElement element through Selenium

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

I have a Select Element that I am testing. I need to Assert that a certain option with user-specified text does not exist inside this Select Element, and also Assert that another option with user-specified text does exist in a SelectElement.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: I have not tried any code, as I do not know of a proper way to Assert on this. SelectElement class doesn't seem to include a method to check this. The page is a private page

Comment: I understand you don't "know" but I guess my point is with all the tutorials, the docs on Select, other questions here... surely you could have read some of those and come up with some attempts. SO is not a code writing service. We expect that you put forth the effort to research your question and make at least some attempt on your own. If you've already done that, please update your question so we can see what you have read and tried so we can better advise you.

Comment: If you take a look at my history here on SO, you will see that I do try to make any and all attempts before asking questions, and do provide what I have already tried with code samples. For this particular inquiry, I found nothing after doing my own research, and have come up with nothing even after 2 years of writing Selenium code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is one way to do it, although performance suffers a bit

```
    public static bool SelectElementContainsItemText(SelectElement selElem, string itemText)
    {
        bool found = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < selElem.Options.Count; i++)
        {
            var blah = selElem.Options[i].Text;
            if (selElem.Options[i].Text.Equals(itemText))
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return found;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This would work:

```
public bool OptionListContains(SelectElement select, string expectedValue)
{
    IList<IWebElement> options = select.Options;
    List<string> optionsText = options.Select(a => a.Text).ToList();
    return optionsText.Contains(expectedValue);
}
```

Just in case you haven't used LINQ queries before you will need:

`using System.Linq;`

Comment: For the select element in question, there are 980 options. I think this will significantly degrade performance, as it first grabs all option's text before checking if one of them contains the text. I think traversing through each option while checking the text at the time of traversal is a better option for performance reasons. My answer does this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in at least 2 ways:

- using xpath, create an element based on your option and check it exists or not, use an xpath like one of the followings:

  //select/option[text()='your_text']
    //select/option[@valur='your_value']
- get the text from all options and check if text contains your string

The first option is easier of course.

Comment: Can you supply the Selenium code with the proper Assert? I don't see any methods inside the SelectElement class where you can check if an element or option exists. That is the part I am stuck on

Comment: Sorry, i don't have/use c# with selenium.Please search some basic tutorials with selenium and c# on google and try some simple tests. see http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#the-5-minute-getting-started-guide